# Access need to not overwrite reports

Tags: ms-access-2007

What is happening here is the report is overriding daily. How can I make the output name unique perhaps with a date? so it will not get deleted each time?

```
Public Function RunDMR()
'E:\Management Reports
Dim myfile As String
myfile = "E:\Management Reports\B3-Daily Fiscal Report on Net Estimated to Receive by Ins - 45.pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "B3: Daily Fiscal Report on Net Estimated to Receive by Ins - 45", acFormatPDF, myfile, False

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a date to the report name, use the following:

```
myfile = "E:\Management Reports\B3-Daily Fiscal Report on Net Estimated to Receive by Ins - 45_" & format(date,"YYYYMMDD") & ".pdf"
```

To add a date & time to the report name, use the following:

```
myfile = "E:\Management Reports\B3-Daily Fiscal Report on Net Estimated to Receive by Ins - 45_" & format(Now(),"YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS") & ".pdf"
```